# How to include more of the request URL in the session cookie path in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat7, multi-tenant

By default Tomcat uses the web application name (context path) as the session cookie path when it generates a session cookie. Is there a way to influence this programmatically? I'd like to include a subset of the servlet path. (This is for a multi-tenant web application where a user can be logged in to more than one tenant at a time, in different windows.) I don't want to set it to a fixed string in a configuration file.

Comment: May be this will help http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig.html

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov Thanks for the link. That feature is new in Servlet 3.0, I wasn't aware of it, and it does allow programmatic influence of the cookie path. Unfortantely it doesn't let me configure the cookie path differently for different servlet path prefixes, because the servlet context that it's attached to is global (or at least global per JVM).